# How to create time based queue with priority in Python?

Tags: python, priority-queue

I need to create jobs queue with certain time frame and priority, like

```
name      time                              priority
-----------------------------------------------------
Job 1:    from 13:00 till 14:00 5.5.2018    10
Job 2:    from 14:00 till 15:00 5.5.2018    10
Job 3:    from 14:00 till 15:00 5.5.2018    1
```

Now what I need is to allow Job 3 to override Job 2 because it has greater priority and to take its place. I managed to create job queue with priority using this https://pymotw.com/2/Queue/

But I need to have time frames. The program must give me info that Job 2 is delayed or canceled, in case Job 3 takes its place.

The execution result should be

```
Job 1 (because it has closest time)
Job 3 (because it has higher priority than Job 2)
Job 2 (would not execute, because Job 3 took its place)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure that the items you push in your priority queue can order naturally according to your criteria (e.g.: first datetime, then priority).

Inserting tuples in the form `(datetime, priority, jobname)` would do the job:

```
import heapq
import dateutil
import dateutil.parser
h = []

# push items into queue:
heapq.heappush(h, (dateutil.parser.parse('13:00-14:00 5.5.2018'), 10, 'Job 1'))
heapq.heappush(h, (dateutil.parser.parse('14:00-15:00 5.5.2018'), 10, 'Job 2'))
heapq.heappush(h, (dateutil.parser.parse('14:00-15:00 5.5.2018'), 1, 'Job 3'))

# extract items from queue:
print(heapq.heappop(h))
# (datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 5, 13, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -50400)), 10, 'Job 1')
print(heapq.heappop(h))
# (datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 5, 14, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -54000)), 1, 'Job 3')
print(heapq.heappop(h))
# (datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 5, 14, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -54000)), 10, 'Job 2')
```

Comment: I get the error NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined. Also I need the timeframe, from - to. OK, maybe I could use starting time and duration.

Comment: @emir: where'd you get that `datetime` from? Not from my code I suppose.

Comment: Now it is commented, and there is no error now, but when I run it nothing happens.

Comment: @emir: the `dateutil.parser` would pick the start date. If you have a different criteria for establishing the priority of such datetime range, you need to transform it to some orderable data type.

Comment: @emir: try to `print(heapq.heappop(...))` each of the last 3 lines

Comment: Thank you for the code, but this should not execute Job3 first, Job1 is earlier and it should be firts, and then Job3 because it has greater priority then Job2

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't get that right. So you want to order first by date, then by priority... I've edited my answer.

Comment: It is better now. It sorts by time, and then by priority. Only problem here is that job that is replaced still executes. It must not execute. Also is this dateutil.parser.parse('14:00-15:00 5.5.2018') time range from 14h till 15h